# user.check_password assertion failing

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have some tests trying to validate my user creation process in an API application.

The issue I am having is that when I try to validate a users password was created as a hashed object the test is failing.

Test:

```
CREATE_USER_URL = reverse('user:create')


def create_user(**params):
    return get_user_model().objects.create_user(**params)
...

def test_create_valid_user_success(self):
        """Test creating user with valid user is successful"""
        payload = {
            'email': 'test@email.com',
            'password': 'testpass',
            'name': 'Test Name'
        }
        res = self.client.post(CREATE_USER_URL, payload)

        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        user = get_user_model().objects.get(**res.data)
        self.assertTrue(user.check_password(payload['password']))
        self.assertNotIn('password', res.data)
```

Serializer:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

from rest_framework import serializers


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for users object"""

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('email', 'password', 'name')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {
                'write_only': True,
                'min_length': 8
            }
        }

        def create(self, validated_data):
            """Create a new user with encrypted password and return it"""
            return get_user_model().objects.create_user(**validated_data)
```

Failed Test:

```
FAIL: test_create_valid_user_success (user.tests.test_user_api.PublicUserApiTests)
Test creating user with valid user is successful
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/user/tests/test_user_api.py", line 33, in test_create_valid_user_success
    self.assertTrue(user.check_password(payload['password']))
AssertionError: False is not true
```

From what I can tell from documentation etc, I have the correct syntax.

Wjhat is missing/incorrect that I need in order to fix this error?

Comment: Are you sure the password is getting hashed. If you print `user.password`, do you see a hashed password (so something of the form `...$...$...`).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, you're right, it's not being hashed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue was indentation in my `UserSerializer` class.

See this issue:

[Django users being created with cleartext passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61857290/django-users-being-created-with-cleartext-passwords/61858217#61858217)